# Why two pvt keys generated in registering and enrolling admin identity

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, certificate-authority, hyperledger-fabric-ca

While installing fabric ca, when we run below command while creating container- 
 'fabric-ca-server start -b admin:adminpw'
it registers the admin user creates a cert.pem and a private key in keystore inside msp folder (in the fabric-ca docker container directory)

and when we enroll it by using following command-
* fabric-ca-client enroll -d -u http://admin:adminpw@0.0.0.0:7054'
It creates one more private key in the keystore inside msp folder and other certs.

I wanted to know the difference between these two private keys generated.

Answer (score 0):

One private key is for ca-cert.pem and the other is for `tls-cert.pem`. You can match cert file and corresponding private key is using below commands.

```
openssl pkey -in <name of private key> -pubout -outform pem | sha256sum 
openssl x509 -in <name of cert file> -pubkey -noout -outform pem | sha256sum
```

For further info, please visit
https://www.sslshopper.com/certificate-key-matcher.html